# How to add two data base connection in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce open source shopping cart.
I have problem.
I want to get only Stock Quantity from another database.
So I thing I want to add a another data base connection string.
 How can I do it??

I want to show data from two data base in the same view.

Plz give me the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nopcommerec has yet not provide such facilities to add more then one data source.instead of that you need to write webservice to consume stock data

Comment: can you please explain how can I do it? I don't have any idea about it? Plz help..

Comment: It is possible to do add plugin??

Answer (score -1):

create stock table in nopccommerec and write web serverice in InstallationService.cs in(NOP.Service/Installation). which will insert value in stock table while installing NOP Application.

Comment: but this doesn't help if the stock control has to be dynamic and if its needs to be get on the fly from a remote data source ..

Comment: write a web service to access the remote database.if you want it all values during installation then add web service in installtionService.cs.